# How to sync account in Java with two persons

Tags: java, wait, notify

You have 1 account, shared by 2 people, they need to extract and deposit money in the same account, methods deposit and extract must be synchronized, the max cash for the account must be 500 €, and the minimum cash must be 1€, the app must have only 3 classes Persona, Cuenta, BPA.

If one Thread can't deposit or extract must use wait, to wait the another thread, and use notify All, when the Thread stopped should continue, the app will need running until both Threads can't deposit and extract cash.

The threads don't stop on the wait, or just execute 2 prints each thread and app still running but doing nothing, i really don't know how to do it, I'm literally 5 hours with that code without understand nothing

```
package BPA;

// @author Enrique
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class BPA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cuenta laCuenta = new Cuenta(40, 500);

        Persona Ramon = new Persona("Ramon", laCuenta);
        Persona Quique = new Persona("Quique", laCuenta);

        Quique.start();
        Ramon.start();

    }// END MAIN

}//END CLASS BPA
```

```
package BPA;

// @author Enrique
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Persona extends Thread {

    String nombre;
    private Cuenta cuenta;
    private static Object cerrojo = new Object();

    public Persona(String nombre, Cuenta cuenta) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cuenta = cuenta;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (cerrojo) {
            while (true) {
                cuenta.deposit(nombre, cuenta);
                cuenta.extract(nombre, cuenta);

                try {
                    // if(Persona.interrupted()){
                    cerrojo.wait();
                    System.out.println("STOPPED");
                    // }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("I'M THE THREAD: " + nombre);
                cerrojo.notifyAll();
            }
       } // END SYNC
    }// END RUN

}// END CLASS PERSONA
```

```
package BPA;

// @author Enrique
import java.util.Random;

public class Cuenta extends Thread {

    private int saldo;
    private int saldoMax = 500;
    private int saldoMin = 1;

    public Cuenta(int saldo, int saldoMax) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
        this.saldoMax = saldoMax;
    }

    public synchronized void extract(String nombre, Cuenta cuenta) {
        //  while (true) {
        int dinero;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        dinero = (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * 250.0);
        if ((saldo - dinero) > saldoMin) {
            this.saldo = this.saldo - dinero;
            System.out.println("Name: " + nombre + " extract cash: " + dinero + " TOTAL CASH: " + getSaldo());
        } else {
            System.out.println("There isn't enough cash " + nombre + " tryed to extract: " + dinero + " Cash now: " + getSaldo());
            // try {
            // miCuenta.wait();
            // System.out.println("SE PARA EN EL WAIT DE QUITAR");
            // } catch (Exception e) {
            // System.out.println("SALE POR EL CATCH WAIT de QUITAR");
            // }
            try {
                sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(" SLEEP QUITAR");
            }
        }
        //  miCuenta.notify();
        //  } //END while

    }// END METHOD QUITAR

    public synchronized void deposit(String nombre, Cuenta cuenta) {
        //   while (true) {
        int dinero;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        dinero = (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * 250.0);

        if ((saldo + dinero) < saldoMax) {
            this.saldo = this.saldo + dinero;
            System.out.println("Name: " + nombre + " deposit cash: " + dinero + " TOTAL CASH: " + getSaldo());

        } else {
            System.out.println("The account can't have more than 500 Euros. " + nombre + " tryed to deposit: " + dinero + " Cash now: " + getSaldo());
                //  try {
                //  miCuenta.wait();
                //  System.out.println(" WAIT PONER");
                //   } catch (Exception e) {
                //  System.out.println(" CATCH WAIT PONER");
                //   }
            try {
                sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(" SLEEP  PONER");
            }
        }
        // miCuenta.notify();
        // }// END while

    }// END METHOD PONER

        public int getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }


}// END CLASS CUENTA
```

I can't make this app run as I want to do.

Comment: But what's the error you are seeing? What specifically?

Comment: The threads don't stop on the wait, or just execute 2 prints each thread and app still running but doing nothing, i really dont know how to do it, im literaly 5 hours with that code without understand nothing

Answer (score 0):

The error was, I was trying to make wait and notify in the wrong class, the Threads needs to be synchronized in methods deposit and extract, to be controlled. I left here the code if some one else need it.

```
package BPA;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class BPA {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cuenta laCuenta = new Cuenta(40, 500);
    Persona Ramon = new Persona("Ramon", laCuenta);
    Persona Quique = new Persona("Quique", laCuenta);
    Quique.start();
    Ramon.start();
    try {
        Quique.join();
        Ramon.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {      
     System.out.println("Interrupted");
    }
}// END MAIN
}//END CLASS BPA




 package BPA;
// @author Enrique

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

 public class Persona extends Thread {

String nombre;
private Cuenta cuenta;

public Persona(String nombre, Cuenta cuenta) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.cuenta = cuenta;
}

@Override
public synchronized void run() {
    while (true) {
        cuenta.ingreso(nombre, cuenta);
        cuenta.retiro(nombre, cuenta);
        try {
            sleep(1000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" SLEEP QUITAR");
        }
        notifyAll();
    }// END WHILE
}// END RUN
} // END CLASS PERSONA



  package BPA;
 // @author Enrique

import java.util.Random;

public class Cuenta {

private int saldo;
private int saldoMax = 500;
private int saldoMin = 1;

public Cuenta(int saldo, int saldoMax) {
    this.saldo = saldo;
    this.saldoMax = saldoMax;
}

public synchronized void retiro(String nombre, Cuenta cuenta) {
    int dinero;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    dinero = (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * 350.0);
    if ((saldo - dinero) > saldoMin) {
        this.saldo = this.saldo - dinero;
        System.out.println("Name: " + nombre + " extract cash: " + dinero + " TOTAL CASH: " + getSaldo());
        notifyAll();
    } else {
        System.out.println("  ****  There isn't enough cash " + nombre + " tryed to extract: " + dinero + " Cash now: " + getSaldo() + " ****");
        System.out.println(" ---- " + nombre + " IS WAITING TO EXTRACT MORE MONEY ---- ");
        try {
            wait();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SALE POR EL CATCH WAIT de QUITAR");
        }
    }
}// END METHOD QUITAR

public synchronized void ingreso(String nombre, Cuenta cuenta) {

    int dinero;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    dinero = (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * 350.0);

    if ((saldo + dinero) < saldoMax) {
        this.saldo = this.saldo + dinero;
        System.out.println("Name: " + nombre + " deposit cash: " + dinero + " TOTAL CASH: " + getSaldo());
        notifyAll();
    } else {
        System.out.println(" **** The account can't have more than 500 Euros. " + nombre + " tryed to deposit: " + dinero + " Cash now: " + getSaldo() + " ****");
        System.out.println(" ---- " + nombre + " IS WAITING TO DEPOSIT MORE MONEY ---- ");
        try {
            wait();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" CATCH WAIT PONER");
        }
    }
}// END METHOD PONER

public int getSaldo() {
    return saldo;
}
}// END CLASS CUENTA
```